# Change option textbox size product page Opencart

Tags: css, opencart

Hi im trying to change the textbox size of an option textbox thats on my product pages,

The problem is that it will change all textbox sizes on the website cause it uses the same css property, so the textboxes of the login also increase in size at (index.php?route=account/login)

How can i make it so that only the product page textboxes increase

```
input[type="text"], input[type="password"], textarea {
background: #F8F8F8;
border: 1px solid #CCC;
padding: 3px;
margin-left: 0px;
margin-right: 0px;
width: 279px;             <= "Added by me "
```

Answer (score 1):

check body class on products page and add it before input in css. Example:

```
body.product-class input{

}
```

or add class to inputs on product page.

Comment: I have added a custom  body and class to each page of my website, how can i change the textbox on this page? 

   <body id="pproduct" class="pproduct class-product-product product-53 product-a-">